# Adding a dynamic div which moves while scrolling using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to dynamically show a div just beside a button when it is clicked. I do it using the following code:

```
$('#mainId').css({ 'top': position, "position": "absolute", "class": "editingContent", "display": "none" });
$('#mainId').slideToggle("fast");
```

where mainid is the id of the div i want to show.

The problem is this div remains at the same position even when I scroll down.
I tried changing the position to relative - but in this case the div ends up at the end of the page,

I want this div to shown up next to the button clicked. But it should also move up (or down) when I scroll  the web page up (or down).

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5L5p523b/

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What the meaning of `"class": "editingContent"` inside the CSS object?

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML and/or create a jsfiddle that reproduces this. I suspect the problem lies with something that you haven't shown.

Comment: You cannot put a div inside a button, but you could position both inside a relatively-positioned wrapper. Bottom line is that this needs more markup to work well.

Comment: You can, but shouldn't. All he needs to do is just put position relative on the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously have more work to do, but the simple answer to allow the content div to scroll with the parent element is setting the parent div to position relative, so that the absolutely positioned content div is positioned relative to the outer div. Here is updated fiddle:

```
<div style="height:50px;overflow:auto; position:relative">

    <button id="ibutton"> Content </button>
    <div id="somediv">Here is the content.</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5L5p523b/1/

Keep in mind this achieves what you are asking, but I'd honestly consider floating these elements, and toggling show/hide with animation (since that is what you are doing in the fiddle) for a more flexible layout. There is also pure css3 solutions out there as well, if you have the time to research.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating buttons and info manually, why don't you wrap a div to both of them and simple show/hide the info on button click. It will follow the page scroll.

#### DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/5L5p523b/2/

#### HTML

```
<div style="height:500px;overflow:auto;">
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <div class="btn-div">
        <button id="ibutton2" class="ibtn">Content</button>
        <div id="somediv2" class="info">Here is the content.</div>
    </div>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <div class="btn-div">
        <button id="ibutton" class="ibtn">Content</button>
        <div id="somediv" class="info">Here is the content.</div>
    </div>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.btn-div {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    padding:10px;
}
.info {
    display:none;
}
```